# Анимация jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код html:

```
<div class="album">
<div id="content">
<div class="album">
<div id="content">
<div class="album">
<div id="content">
<div class="album">
<div id="content">
```

Код js:

```
 function albumslide (){
     $(".album").toggle(function (){
       $(this).next().slideUp(1000);  
     }, 
     function() {
         $(this).next().slideDown(1000);  
     });         
 }
```

При нажатии на "album" весь тэг "content" должен сворачиваться. Что тут неправильно? Все правильно подключено, не работает только эта функция.

Comment: за такой код вообще по рукам бить надо! чё за дивы без закрывающихся тэгов да и ещё с одинаковыми ID?????

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.album').click(function() {
 $('#content').toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="album">
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var hidden = false;
                $('.album').click(function() {

                    if (hidden == false) {
                        hidden == true;
                        $('#content').slideUp(1000);
                    } else {
                        hidden == false;
                        $('#content').slideDown(1000);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: только id везде разные должны быть